# Long retry framework in Java

Tags: java, spring-retry

I am looking for a Java library to help with implementing a retry mechanism that can survive restarts of the JVM. I want to be able to retry for days and to continue to retry after the retrying application has restarted. The use case is for a long running (hours, possibly days) task submitted from a northbound application that requires a REST call (essentially a REST Hook) from my application to indicate the task has completed. It's possible that the northbound system won't be available when the task has completed. In the past we have used JMS for this communication, but we have been forced to seek a REST solution now.

My favored idea at the moment is to use Spring Retry and implement my own RetryContextCache that persists to a database. Are there any other approaches I could consider?